# OpenCV Error. Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument '%s', What kind of error is this?

Tags: ocr, opencv, python

Below I have provided the snippet of the code

```
kernel=np.ones((1, 1), np.float32)
img=cv2.dilate(pages[0], kernel, iterations=1)
img=cv2.erode(pages[0], kernel, iterations=1)
text=str(pt.image_to_string(img))
```

I am getting some errors in the second line of the above code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's `pages[0]`? Is it probably a string? Indicating some image file (path)? If so, you'd need to actually read the image, e.g. using `cv2.imread(pages[0])`. For the dilation and erosion, the image must be grayscale. So, `cv2.imread(pages[0], cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)` might be beneficial.

Comment: pages[0] is an image extracted from a pdf
Thanks for the advice, will try the grayscale following up with dilation and erosion and let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is because pages[0] is not the right form.
cv2.Umat() is functionally equivalent to np.float32(), so your code should read:

```py
img = cv2.dilate(np.float32(pages[0]), kernel, iterations=1)
img = cv2.erode(np.float32(pages[0]), kernel, iterations=1)
```